# помогите с поиском по DOM

Tags: javascript

есть такой вот html. и стоило бы сделать так - кликаем плюсик в div'e , добавляем +1 , кликаем еще раз , добавляем еще +1 , и тд. и так для каждого отдельного div

```
<div class="container">  
   <div class="border" id="part1">            
            <div class="image">
                <img src="image.jpg"/>                           
            </div>        
            <div class="basket_price_block">
                 <div class="basket_price">
                    <span id="product1_price" class="product_price">0</span>
                    <span >amount</span>                    
                    <input class="number" name="number"/>
                    <div class="plus"> + </div>
                </div>            
            </div>                         
        </div> 
       <div class="border" id="part2">            
            <div class="image">
                <img src="image.jpg"/>                           
            </div>        
            <div class="basket_price_block">
                 <div class="basket_price">
                    <span id="product1_price" class="product_price">0</span>
                    <span >amount</span>                    
                    <input class="number" name="number"/>
                    <div class="plus"> + </div>
                </div>            
            </div>                         
        </div>  
       <div class="border" id="part3">            
            <div class="image">
                <img src="image.jpg"/>                           
            </div>        
            <div class="basket_price_block">
                 <div class="basket_price">
                    <span id="product1_price" class="product_price">0</span>
                    <span >amount</span>                    
                    <input class="number" name="number"/>
                    <div class="plus"> + </div>
                </div>            
            </div>                         
        </div>  
 </div>
```

js 
пробовал так, но спан берется всегда один и тот же , может как то через this сделать

```
for (var i=0;i<plus.length;i++){
                plus[i].addEventListener( "click", function(event) {
                  var parent = event.target.parentNode,   
                       sum = 0 ;               
                  var chosenSpan = parent.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML; 
                  calc = parseInt(sum)+parseInt(chosenSpan);
                  alert(sum);

                });
   }
```

Comment: как вы выбираете `plus`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.plus').click(function(){
    var b = $(this).parent().find('.product_price').text();
    var c = b/1 + 1;
    $(this).parent().find('.product_price').text(c);
})
```

Быстрый пример кода

Comment: у , нужен ответ на чистом js

Answer (score 2):

```
var plus = document.querySelectorAll('div.plus');

for (var i=0;i<plus.length;i++){
    plus[i].addEventListener( "click", function(event) {
        var parent = event.target.parentNode,   
            span = parent.getElementsByTagName("span")[0],
            sum = span.innerHTML;

        span.innerHTML = parseInt(sum) + 1;
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t7dxo14v/

Comment: отлично! но извольте за нескромный вопрос - как оно работает то , в плане выполнения скрипта

Comment: parent = event.target.parentNode,  - поучаем родителя кнопки, span = parent.getElementsByTagName("span")[0], - получаем спан, sum = span.innerHTML; - получаем значение (текст), span.innerHTML = parseInt(sum) + 1; - меняем текст спана, поставте галочку на верном ответе

Comment: с этим вроде понятно, а вот самое интересное это 
var plus = document.querySelectorAll('div.plus');

Comment: Это мы получаем набор элементов ( в данном случаве div'ы с классом plus), и потом ходим в цикле по ним и вешаем обработчики событий

Comment: теперь ясно, а вот если понадобится в поле input добавлять значение , некого счетчика, что бы по плюсу там было 1 потом 2 и тд. тогда нужно добавлять 
input = document.querySelectorAll('input.number');
а потом в цикле 
input.innerHTML.value = +1 ; 
я правильно понимаю?

Comment: это набор, вам нужно будет выбрать нужный вам интпут, такая вот тавтология, сделайте console.log(plus), и все поймете, но в целом да

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам подойдет это решение. Правда по вашим условиям, всегда будет 0

```js
var plus = document.querySelectorAll('.plus')

for (var i = 0; i < plus.length; i++) {
  plus[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var parent = event.target.parentNode,
      sum = 0,
      chosenSpan = parent.querySelector('.product_price').innerHTML;
    var calc = sum + parseInt(chosenSpan, 10);
    alert(calc);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="border" id="part1">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="basket_price_block">
      <div class="basket_price">
        <span id="product1_price" class="product_price">110</span>
        <span>4</span> 
        <input class="number" name="number" />
        <div class="plus">+</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="border" id="part2">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="basket_price_block">
      <div class="basket_price">
        <span id="product1_price" class="product_price">120</span>
        <span>3</span> 
        <input class="number" name="number" />
        <div class="plus">+</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="border" id="part3">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="basket_price_block">
      <div class="basket_price">
        <span id="product1_price" class="product_price">130</span>
        <span>2</span> 
        <input class="number" name="number" />
        <div class="plus">+</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```